# How do I merge pandas df with multiple columns using one key from another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with two columns `A` and `B` (df1)

```
A   B
1   2
1   3
2   3
```

And a Dataframe (df2) with a "dictionary" describing `1`, `2` and `3`

```
O   P   Q
1   s   a
2   s   b
3   t   b
```

Now I want to `merge` the first table with the second table such that I get the following:

```
A   B   P1   Q1   P2   Q2
1   2    s    a    s    b
1   3    s    a    t    b
2   3    s    b    t    b
```

I've tried `df1.merge(df2, left_on=["A","B"], right_on=["O","O"])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate merging schemes here, so you'll have to call [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) twice:

```
(df1.merge(df2, left_on="A", right_on="O")
    .merge(df2, left_on="B", right_on="O")
    .drop(columns=['O_x', 'O_y']))

   A  B P_x Q_x P_y Q_y
0  1  2   s   a   s   b
1  1  3   s   a   t   b
2  2  3   s   b   t   b
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought maybe I was missing some generalization that would've allowed me to use the df2 as some sort of "dictionary" for df1. Much appreciated.